# NinJump Like game Swift (Score updating issue)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nstimer

I'm trying to create Ninjump like game using Swift UIKit. everything was working fine until i added scores label. This is actually weird and I can't figure out why its happeing. 
So I have a enemy which movies 15px down when timer updates. and One ninja, which moves from left to right when touched on screen. And Score updates when enemy moves out of screen. Whats happening is, score is updating to 1...2..3 when enemies go out of screen. But whenever the score is updating, Ninja moves to left automatically if at right. I don't know why its happening. Its happening everytime when one enemy goes out of the screen. Here's my code

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Ninja: UIImageView!
    var score = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    var startGame = NSTimer()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.updateNinja()
    }

    var enemyImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(32, -300, 100, 100))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scoreLabel.text = "0"
        enemyImage.image = UIImage(named: "enemy")
        self.view.addSubview(self.enemyImage)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        startGame = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }




    func update() {

        if CGRectIntersectsRect(self.Ninja.frame, self.enemyImage.frame) {
            println("Game Over")
        }

        // show the enemy again and again
        if self.enemyImage.frame.origin.y > self.view.frame.height {
            self.enemyImage.frame.origin.y = -100
            score++ // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
            self.scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

        }

        // move the enemy image downwards
        enemyImage.frame.origin.y += 15

    }




    var isLeft:Bool = false // check where is the ninja left/right

    func updateNinja() {

        if isLeft {
            isLeft = false
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.Ninja.frame.origin.x = 32
             })

        } else {
            isLeft = true
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.Ninja.frame.origin.x = self.rightBar.frame.origin.x - 50
                }) 
        }

      }

}
```

and whats more weird is when I remove **score++** its working fine.

**Update**: Its happeing when I'm trying to update the scoreLabel's text. any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hide that label and try creating a new label programatically, update the new label for scores. Let me know if it works for you, It happened to me once as well.